# How to get disk usage from command line?

Tags: command-line, disk-usage

How can I get the current disk usage (in %) of my hard drive from the command line?

Comment: Now I wonder if there's some commandline equivalent of `kdirstat` or `baobab`.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/9847/linux-utility-for-finding-the-largest-files-directories

Answer (score 186, accepted):

By using the `df` command.

Here's an example output:

```
$ df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1            303537496  27537816 260580948  10% /
none                    950788       252    950536   1% /dev
none                    959516       232    959284   1% /dev/shm
none                    959516       388    959128   1% /var/run
none                    959516         0    959516   0% /var/lock
```

Also take a look at its [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/df.1.html).

Comment: `df -m` will show things in megabytes, `df -h` will show you in the largest possible unit.

Answer (score 209):

## [ncdu](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu)

Works well from the command line. It's ncurses-based and interactive.
You can install it with `sudo apt-get install ncdu`.

[image]

### Alternatives

- Top ten: `du -shx * | sort -rh | head -10`
- If you want more fine grained disk usage, you should take a look at the [answers here](https://superuser.com/questions/12611/finding-whats-using-all-the-space-in-nix/604730#604730).

Comment: Install this via `sudo apt install ncdu`

Comment: I liked the alternatives. You have to be in the directory you are looking for the large files. But I found it easy to spot the culprit this way without having to install anything.

Comment: `du -shx * | sort -rh | head -10` is a lifesaver! Especially great if you are on a small test server, you have run out of space, and do not already have a fancy utility installed to fix your problems.

Comment: on CentOS `sudo yum install ncdu`

Comment: The Top ten item above is very helpful, however, it omits hidden directories.  Is there an easy way to include them?

Comment: Oh my god I almost died here! While in this tool, be VERY CAREFUL not to think you're on the command line and do `cd folder` because D is DELETE and space will CONFIRM :O